# How to mock db outages using hsqdb?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, hsqldb

I'm using HSQLDB for unit testing.
Is there a good way to mock various db issues like constraint violations, ORM layer exceptions or outright db outages while using HSQLDB w/o explicitly mocking the ORM layer?

Answer (score 0):

For an outage you can try not to start the DB. For all other things I would prefer mocking the ORM Layer.

BTW: when using HSQLDB it's actually not Unit-Testing anymore. It's more of an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that that's very difficult to do, since an in-memory database doesn't really become disconnected or similar. There's a few options for your situation though:

- To fake constraint violations, do something that breaks the constraint. E.g. for unique constraints add a duplicate row beforehand, for foreign key constraints delete the referenced foreign row when the system-under-test doesn't expect it, etc.
- ORM layer exceptions are tricky. Doing wild things to the database is probably the easiest way to get some reaction here (e.g. delete all the tables), but I think you're going to struggle to reproduce many of the possible problems.
- DB outages aren't really directly fakeable with an in-memory database, since it's really always accessible. The solution is to get into the layer between the system-under-test and the database, and break the connection there, is possible. I'm currently doing this on a Java project using Spring and JDBC templates, and I'm mocking DB timeouts and outages respectively with:

```
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = 
              ((DriverManagerDataSource)jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());

// 192.0.2.1 is in the TEST-NET range, guaranteed 
// to never exist, so this always times out

dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:http://192.0.2.1/testdb");

// Subsequent operations then timeout
```

and

```
// Port 9 is reserved for 'discard', so is almost certainly unconnectable 
// and very very unlikely to ever actually return valid data even if not.

dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:http://localhost:9/testdb");

// Subsequent operations immediately fail to connect
```

Note that both of these will break new connections, as far as I can tell there's no way to break all current open connections. If you can get a reference to one though, close()ing it should get pretty close to simulating a mid-flight disconnection.

Also, as boutta pointed out, this is an integration test, not a unit test. In addition to doing these integration tests you probably also want to unit test the code you have talking to the DB here, and mock out your database interface (e.g. your JDBC template) entirely for that. This actually makes lots of things much easier, particularly simulation of specific exception scenarios.